# Moved file from terminal and can't find it anymore

Tags: command-line, terminal, mv

I have moved file from the terminal and can't find it anywhere on my mac. I guess, I made a mistake when writing the mv command. 
This is the line I have written :

```
mv aiw_icham002 ~/Desktop/Goldsmiths/Software\ Projects
```

before projects I have used "\", because I have read somewhere that if there is space in the name folder I have to use \ before the actual space.
Thank you in advance.
Ivan

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, did "Software Projects" exists before you did that mv command? Do `ls -l ~/Desktop/Goldsmiths` -- is "Software Projects" a file or a directory?

Comment: My mistake the file is in Goldsmiths with the name Software projects, my folder' name is Software project and not projects. However this changed the name of the file and I need the file to be named aiw_icham002 due to grading requirements, should I just change the name of the file and move it to the folder manually or ?

Comment: Then do `cd ~/Desktop/Goldsmiths; mv "Software Projects" "Software Project/aiw_icham002"`

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you do need the `\` to break the space character. If the terminal didn't give you an error, the file should be at `Users/{username}/Desktop/Goldsmiths/Software Projects`.

If the folder did not exist, then you simply renamed the file to `Software Projects` in the `/Goldsmiths` folder.